# Simple Raw SQl query - I'm a SQL noob

Tags: views

I am using the views Raw SQL plugin.

I have a simple raw SQL query where I want the result in a field to be a positive number otherwise 0 if it is a negative number:

This is what I have:

((votingapi_cache_node_polarity_sum.value / votingapi_cache_node_polarity_count.value) * 100)

How can I modify this query so that the result is a positive number only or 0.

The client wants this calculation:

Positive votes/total votes = voting score

using vote results from the positive - negative rate widget.
Its not an average a calculation of the voting score or average number of votes.

Comment: if you use mysql engine, then you can use [control flow functions][1]. E.g. 

    ((case when votingapi_cache_node_polarity_sum.value>0 then (votingapi_cache_node_polarity_sum.value/votingapi_cache_node_polarity_count.value) * 100) else 0 end


  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this. Are you saying that raw sql alone in views will not solve the problem? How do I use the mysql engine?

Comment: I think @Nikit means that you can use database specific code to accomplish this. If you are using MySQL, as opposed to PostgreSQL, or some other database, you can use non-standard SQL to return the results you are looking for.